# "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" error

Tags: python, web2py

I'm seeing weird behavior on this code:

```
images = dict(cover=[],second_row=[],additional_rows=[])

for pic in pictures:
    if len(images['cover']) == 0:
        images['cover'] = pic.path_thumb_l
    elif len(images['second_row']) < 3:
        images['second_row'].append(pic.path_thumb_m)
    else:
        images['additional_rows'].append(pic.path_thumb_s)
```

My web2py app gives me this error:

> ```
> if len(images['cover']) == 0:
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
> ```

I can't figure out what's wrong in this. Maybe some scope issue?

Comment: You are asking for the Length of a variable that contains None.  None is a special value (of type NoneType) that has no length.  Before you check for the length of something, first check to make sure it does not have the value "None".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You assign something new to `images['cover']`:

```
images['cover'] = pic.path_thumb_l
```

where `pic.path_thumb_l` is `None` at some point in your code.

You probably meant to append instead:

```
images['cover'].append(pic.path_thumb_l)
```

Answer (score 16):

your problem is that

`if len(images['cover']) == 0:`

checks the LENGTH of the value of images['cover'] what you meant to do is check if it HAS a value.

do this instead:

`if not images['cover']:`

Comment: Actually it was due the assignment of some "None" to images['cover'] (as pointed by Martjin). But thanks!

Comment: in your post you said that this line `if len(images['cover']) == 0:` gave you the error...

Comment: either way, you should change your code to `if not images['cover']:` instead, since if the length is not 0 it will already have a value, this way its more pythonic :)

Comment: Yes. In the second iteration inside the for, `images['cover']` type was "None", as the first iteration assigned some "None" value to it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's true. Will do that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

We can also see the type in the same condition, to avoid something if you want, like

```
if myArray is None:
    #Do something when array has no len()
else:
    #Do something when array has elements and has len()
```

In my case I was looking for something in the array, but only if has something, when id does not, was None the type and I need to create it. Hope this works for someones.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you assign: `images['cover'] = pic.path_thumb_l`, it replaces the value of the empty list initially stored in `images['cover']` with the value of `pic.path_thumb_l` which is `None`.

Maybe your code in this line must be `images['cover'].append(pic.path_thumb_l)`